# Pyspark: merge conditions in a when clause

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would appreciate some help to merge lines that get TYPE2 and type3.

I would need just one line to get TYPE2 and one line to get TYPE3:

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("DEVICETYPE",
                        when(length(col("deviceid")) ==21,lit("type1"))
                        .when(col("DEVICESERIALNO").like("1200125%"),lit("type2"))
                        .when(length(col("deviceid")) ==17,lit("type2"))
                        .when(col("DEVICESERIALNO").isNull(),lit("type3"))
                        .when(length(col("deviceid")) ==17,lit("type3"))
                        .when(length(col("deviceid")) ==7,lit("type4"))
                        .when(length(col("deviceid")) ==5,lit("type4"))
                    )
```

Thanks much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&`:

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("DEVICETYPE",
                        when(length(col("deviceid")) ==21,lit("type1"))
                        .when((col("DEVICESERIALNO").like("1200125%")) & (length(col("deviceid")) ==17),lit("type2"))
                        .when((col("DEVICESERIALNO").isNull()) & (length(col("deviceid")) ==17),lit("type3"))
                        .when(length(col("deviceid")) ==7,lit("type4"))
                        .when(length(col("deviceid")) ==5,lit("type4"))
                    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you have multiple conditions for `type2`, `type3` and `type4`. Hence, I would suggest the following modified piece of code:

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("DEVICETYPE",
                        when(length(col("deviceid")) ==21,lit("type1"))
                        .when((col("DEVICESERIALNO").like("1200125%")) & (length(col("deviceid")) ==17),lit("type2"))
                        .when((col("DEVICESERIALNO").isNull()) & (length(col("deviceid")) ==17),lit("type3"))
                        .when((length(col("deviceid")) ==7) & (length(col("deviceid")) ==5),lit("type4"))
                    )
```